# Why AVPlayerItem's canPlayFastForward method returns False?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I really want to implement fast forward and reverse play with AVFoundation.

As far as I know I can only play 0.0 ~ 2.0 rate with AVPlayer if AVPlayerItem's canPlayReverse and canPlayFastForward returns False.

But I need -1.0 and also rate over 2.0.

My problem is that I just can't find **when** and **why** the results is false.

There is no mention about when canPlayFastForward returns false on Apple's doc.

Can anyone explain **when and why** the results of **canPlayFastForward** & **canPlayReverse** is **false** and how can I change it to **true**?

Comment: Report from the trenches: I have gotten *false negatives* from `canPlaybackFastForward` . It returned false, but AVPlayer could play it faster just fine.

Comment: KimCrab - Did you manage to get canPlaybackFastForward to show true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibility is you are checking the `AVPlayerItem`'s `canPlayReverse` or `canPlayFastForward` before the `AVPlayerItem`'s property `status` changes to `.readToPlay`. If you are doing so, you will always get `false`.

**Don't** do like this:

```
import AVFoundation

let anAsset = AVAsset(URL: <#A URL#>)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: anAsset)
let canPlayFastForward = playerItem.canPlayFastForward
if (canPlayFastForward){
   print("This line won't execute")
}
```

Instead observe the `AVPlayerItem`'s property `status`. Following is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1772/_index.html) from Apple:

> AVPlayerItem objects are dynamic. The value of
>   AVPlayerItem.canPlayFastForward will change to YES for all file-based
>   assets and some streaming based assets (if the source playlist offers
>   media that allows it) at the time the item becomes ready to play. The
>   way to get notified when the player item is ready to play is by
>   observing the AVPlayerItem.status property via Key-Value Observing
>   (KVO).

```
import AVFoundation
dynamic var songItem:AVPlayerItem! //Make it instance variable

let anAsset = AVAsset(URL: <#A URL#>)
let songItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: anAsset)
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Ovveride the `observeValue` method in the same class:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let status = change?[.newKey] as? Int{
            if(status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay.rawValue){
               yourPlayer.rate = 2.0 // or whatever you want
            }
        }

    }
```

**Don't forget to remove this class from songItem's status observer**

```
deinit {
        playerItem.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    }
```

Comment: my AVPlayer returns ready to play but canPlayFastForward still returns false even though some of the videos are fast-forwarding at 8x speed. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have tested with videos which were expressly made for slow-motion playback (60 fps and greater), but still I *always* get `NO` on `canPlayFastForward`and `canPlaySlowForward`, even after the status is `readyToPlay`.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the previous answer you can also use [combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine) to track the status change - which is safer and easier.

```
import AVFoundation

// Class variables
let player: AVPlayer?
var anyCancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

// Setting up the asset and player item
let asset: AVAsset = .init(url: <#URL#>)
let item: AVPlayerItem = .init(asset: asset)
player = .init(playerItem: item)

// Subscribing to status changes - it will be auto release
item.publisher(for: \.status)
    .filter({ $0 == .readyToPlay })
    .sink { [weak self] status in
        self?.player?.rate = <#RATE#>
        // Can start playing here...
    }
    .store(in: &anyCancellables)
```